# Is it possible to talk with "a staff"?

Tags: word-usage

> You are having a meeting with an HR staff

This is a quote from this English lesson material.(https://eikaiwa.weblio.jp/information/business-material/address-concerns)

Is this English sentence correct?  I thought the word "staff" is a group of people and that you can talk to a staff member but you can't talk with a staff.

I wonder if my understanding of the word "staff" is correct.

Comment: I recall that many years ago in the UK NHS ***the staff*** was often used to refer to ***the*** senior ["staff nurse"](https://www.nurses.co.uk/blog/what-is-a-staff-nurse/) on duty on the ward (who in my experience was often the one in charge; not all wards always had their own dedicated "sister" on duty). So *"I'll ask staff"* was a common response to patient requests for special treatment.

Comment: A staff can also refer to a long stick, as might be used by a wizard; but I'm guessing you're not planning on having a meeting with a stick... :-)

Comment: Could also be corrected as: "You are having a meeting with an HR staffer"

Comment: staff and staff member or member of the staff.

Comment: A staff is also the set of five lines to write music on. Like the weapon, it isn't very likely to answer when you attempt a conversation.

Answer (score 38):

That is a mistake.  "A staff" is a group of all the workers for a particular company or department.

The text should say "a member of the HR staff".

<sub>A quick glace at that page shows lots of "Japaneseisms" such as the overuse of "Let's" - presumably as a translation of volitional forms of Japanese verbs, and other malaprops like "Talk to me "according" to the situation".</sub>

Comment: At least in my experience in the US, it also wouldn't be uncommon to use the term "staffer" to refer to a single member of a larger staff.

Comment: Could also say "You are having a meeting with an HR staff member".

Comment: At least in UK English, "a staff" wouldn't normally be used in that sense. "The staff", "the rostered staff", "the on-duty staff", "the current shift" or similar would be generally unremarkable.

Comment: @MarkMorganLloyd Although you probably wouldn't "talk to the HR staff" unless you're making a presentation to the entire HR department.

Comment: @Barmar Although "you need to discuss that with the HR staff" (with an implied "somebody from") would probably be in order. In any event, in the UK we don't use "staffer", and the singular is "stave" :-)

Comment: @MarkMorganLloyd Good point. We also sometimes use metonymy: "You need to discuss that with HR".

Comment: @MarkMorganLloyd: Wow that's ambiguous. I interpret "the HR staff" as still a group noun and you need to talk to more than one. (Other uses I've seen result in it meaning one or more.)

Comment: @Joshua It's OK in UK English, just as "you'd need to talk to the Health Centre staff" and so on (standing outside talking to the Health Centre itself would definitely get one some funny looks). I suspect that, as Barmar has suggested, it's a metonym; however a related possibility is that it implies that there's a "front desk" or reception counter which is staffed appropriately... which is of course another can of worms.

Comment: @SamHanley I wonder if that's a regional thing.  Growing up on the west coast, I don't think I've ever heard the term "staffer" before in my life.

Comment: @KirkWoll That's interesting. The term "staffer" is not much used in the UK - though I'm surprised that it isn't on the west coast of the US.

Answer (score 11):

**The other answers here are missing something that may be important.** Though incorrect in American English, it appears that this usage *is* idiomatic in Indian English. **I wouldn't be surprised if this carried over into other dialects, which may explain the usage in the OP.**

From [*The Hindu*:](https://www.thehindu.com/news/national/tamil-nadu/four-inmates-of-anbu-jothi-ashram-escape-from-cuddalore-shelter-home-one-traced-within-hours/article66543607.ece/amp/)

> **A staff** of the home who went up to the first floor on Wednesday morning was shocked to find that four of the inmates were missing.

From [*The Hindustan Times:*](https://www.hindustantimes.com/cities/gurugram-news/vigilance-bureau-glare-on-official-after-gurugram-rta-staff-six-touts-arrested-101676313035004.html)

> So far, we have arrested **a staff** of the Gurugram RTA

From [*India Today*](https://www.indiatoday.in/amp/television/celebrity/story/raghav-juyal-buys-bmw-x5-worth-rs-1-crore-see-pics-1958885-2022-06-06), next to a photo of an employee handing someone a bouquet:

> In another photo, **a staff** is seen presenting him with a bouquet of flowers.

From [The Free Press Journal:](https://www.freepressjournal.in/amp/mumbai/mumbai-labour-enforcement-officer-booked-by-cbi-in-graft-case)

> Around a month back, **one staff** of the company had met the Labour Enforcement Officer (LEO)

Comment: That's simply a mistake that happens to be common in that community. It is not correct English in any country on any continent.

Comment: @VectorGorgoth Yep, and we all speak Shakespearean English, just with a lot (several centuries’ worth) of mistakes that happen to be common in our communities. That’s what language change **is**.

Comment: @VectorGorgoth I know very well what argument I’m making, and it’s not what you seem to take it to be. The fact that a usage is normal in one Anglophone community makes it correct *for that community’s dialect*. No other community can declare its own usage “right” and theirs “wrong”. Conversely, phonemes in “certain Asian countries” put no obligation whatsoever on the rest of the English-speaking world, any more than the rest of us need to [follow US usage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Father–bother_merger) and eliminate the difference between /ɑ/ and /ɒ/. Is that a mispronunciation too?

Answer (score 9):

There is a difference between saying that someone *is staff* and saying that someone *is a staff.*

There is an idiom "X is staff" meaning "X is a member of staff"

**Example**

A: I just saw a tall man with red hair walking into the laboratory. Is he allowed?

B: Don't worry, that's John, he's staff.

---

Examples from the web:

> *I get a ticket while he gets his for free because he is staff for the concert. We leave each other and I wait in the crowd.*
> https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/On_my_Rod/FQtxDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22he+is+staff%22+-member&pg=PT151&printsec=frontcover
>
> *if someone works for you for X hours a week, it does not matter whether he is staff, he is freelance, he is on a contract, he has
> certain employment rights*
> https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/Press_standards_privacy_and_libel/F7V0Lw4TcSEC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22he+is+staff%22+-member&pg=PA311&printsec=frontcover

Answer (score 6):

If the phrase read "you are having a meeting with *the* HR staff" there is nothing odd; you are attending a meeting, and the (entire) HT team is in the meeting. In a small firm, it doesn't seem odd that such meetings would be fairly regular occurrences. But that would take the definite article "the" and not the indefinite article "an". If you were a consultant who regularly met with the entire HR staff of various organizations, it wouldn't be odd to say "you are having a meeting with *an* HR staff," but outside that context, it seems unlikely that the meeting would be with "a staff." Meeting with *the* staff is fine, or *a* staff member, but within the context of a particular firm, there is only one staff, so the indefinite article is odd unless one regularly meets with the entire staff of multiple firms.

Answer (score 0):

That appears to be a mistake. In this context "staff" is collective, referring to a group. To indicate an individual who is part of the staff you could say:

- an HR staff member
- a member of the HR staff
- an HR staffer

Though the latter is probably [less commonly used](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=staffer%2Cstaff+member&year_start=1900&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3&case_insensitive=true), though acceptable, as an AmE speaker.

Comment: This is a pretty good answer, but I take exception to the statement that "staff" is plural. It is not grammatically plural. It's grammatically singular, but it is a collective noun, much like "group" or "family".

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of an indefinite article ("an") with staff:

"You are having an HR staff meeting"

In this case, it's a shortened inversion of "...a meeting with the HR staff", turning "HR staff" into a modifier of "meeting".

Comment: I suggest that there the noun is "meeting" and "HR staff" is an adjectival clause.

Comment: Of course that's right, it functions as an adjective for 'meeting'

Comment: So it's an example of an indefinite article with "meeting", the presence of an adjective is largely irrelevant. Compare with  "You are having a long meeting" which you would not describe as an example of an indefinite article with "long".

Answer (score -1):

I think it could be correct. From [dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/staff):

> a group of persons, as employees, charged with carrying out the work
> of an establishment or executing some undertaking.

So I think it could be that you are meeting with multiple members of HR. It is not the entire HR staff ("the staff") nor is it a single person ("a staff member"). You are meeting a a group of persons who work for HR, aka, an HR staff. Not *the* staff, just *a* staff.

I could also see "talking to a staff" being correct if you are, say, a CEO talking to different working groups. You're meeting with an HR staff at 2pm to discuss the merger, then a different HR staff at 4pm. You couldn't take everyone offline at the same time for this meeting so you broke it into two groups. Each group is "an HR staff".